# Passing an int value from class to another and storing it in an array in Java

Tags: java

I have got 2 classes in my java program, the first class contains a textfield in which i am getting the users input.I am trying to pass an int value from one textfield (users input) and store this value in an array that is contained in another class.

Class 1
This is the first class were i am getting the data from a textfield

```
if (SubmitButton.equals(e.getSource())) {
    int input = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
    myClass2.setAge(input );
}
```

Class 2
This is the class I am trying to store the data from the users input from class 1 into an array

```
public int setAge(int input) {      
    return input;
}
//this is where i am trying to store the value
int[] Age = {input};
```

For some reason the "input" cannot be resolved to a variable

Can some one help please?

Answer (score 1):

Because, variable `input` have method local scope, you can't access it from outside of the method `setAge()`

Answer (score 1):

use `input` variable as instance member variable

Answer (score 0):

```
int input;

public int setAge(int input) {
       this.input=input;
            return input;
        }
//this is where i am trying to store the value
int[] Age = {input};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second class, define your array as a member variable and assign the value.

```
public class MyClass2 {

    private int[] age = new int[1];

    public void setAge(int input) {
        age[0] = input;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to store "input" in Class2 and then put it to at Age array. For this you should have a variable called "input"(I guess your name prefer is this) in class 2. After that you can store this data like this;

```
private int input;
public int setAge(int input) {      
    this.input = input;
    return input;
}
int[] Age = {input};
```